# how to get case insensitive matching with in_array?

Tags: php

if we have

```
$allowimg = array('gif','bmp','jpg','png','jpeg','tif','tiff','tga','psd');
```

and want to make upload center with it if we put this code

```
if(in_array($filetype,$allowimg)){
//pic
$error = 0;
$filedoc = 'pic';
}
else{ echo 'bad file type!';}
```

if user upload my.PNG
its run Else cuz PNG is not == png for php
can anyone help me with this?
and how to secure from file uploads?

```
$filename = explode('.',$nn);
```

is ok? so what if user upload
my.pic.jpg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) the file type!

```
if(in_array(strtolower($filetype),$allowimg)){
//pic
$error = 0;
$filedoc = 'pic';
}
else{ echo 'bad file type!';}
```

**Part two of your question**

While I suggest you to make a new question for each one rather than a set of questions in a single task, here is how I usually get the file name from the string.

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

[`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function gives information of the path thrown to it. You can optionally get a string with just what you want by specifying it in the second parameter.

`$ext` now contains the extension of the file: `jpg` (could be `JPG` `JPg`, etc. Use the code above to fix that).

Comment: i edit my question can you answer part 2 ?

Comment: @masiharastooyi - If you have another question, post another question. Don't just tag on new questions to your current one.

Comment: I second that. and you added the other question after 2 answers were made...

Comment: wow thanks for question rate! :-s

Answer (score 0):

---

---

```
if(in_array(strtolower($filetype),$allowimg)){
```